# App loading time Issue- Android

Tags: android, performance

I am developing an app Similar to Logo Quiz.
I have around 600 images in it.
Now when the app loads for the first time it takes a lot of time to load.
Any solution to that loading time issue?

Comment: Please use android-query library http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/14827292#14827292

Comment: Don't store all images in packaged .apk file. instead load image from server when app first time loads. so it will not take load on startup.

Comment: Thanks Rahul and Armaan,
But I dont want my app to connect to the net.
If my images increase then yes, I will use the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of solution for doing efficient asynchronous image loading. Here is a few of them:

- [Android Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
- [Picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso)
- [Android-Volley](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley)

A more detailed blog post on the last 2 libs: http://blog.bignerdranch.com/3177-solving-the-android-image-loading-problem-volley-vs-picasso/

Comment: No problem. You might want to accept an answer at some point otherwise no one will give you any answers in the future.

Comment: oh yeah I know but you can accept the correct answer http://i.stack.imgur.com/uqJeW.png

Comment: Thanks, new to stackoverflow, hence!

Answer (score 0):

Use universal image loader

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

It will load your image in background and not block the ui

Comment: Nice.. Works great isn't it?

Comment: UIL is a great library yes